# Querying a MYSQL database with a GET variable

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to query my database with the contents of my Get variable, then retrieve the matching url and put the matching url into a variable, what's the best and safest way of doing this?

Comment: [use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: Please explain in a more detailed way what you're exactly trying to archive and post a code example. Thanks

Comment: be prepared to fight SQL Injection

Comment: Thats the problem, I am trying to understand the PHP sql query, but failing.

Answer (score 1):

The best and safest way is to sanitize any value inserted by users in order to prevent [SQL INJECTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  I personally use PDO a library that handles in a clean and safe way the data connection and prepared statement.

Better than GET, use POST method to send and retrieve user data.

Look for [PHP sanitization filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php) as a pre but not unique way of clean user sent values.

This an example of how should a safe query look:

First sanitization:

```
    $user_login=filter_var($_GET['user_login'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

Then query:

```
$query_login=$dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_status FROM usr.view_user_validation WHERE user_email=?;");
$query_login->execute(array($user_login));
```